# TimThumb images not showing - On inspection error is shown

Tags: wordpress

Wondering if you can help me. I have installed a theme that comes with TimThumb.

However when I set the featured image, and view the blog, the images doesn't load, when I right click and click view image in a new tab I get the following error message:

```
A TimThumb error has occured
The following error(s) occured:

    Could note create the index.html file.
    Could note create cache clean timestamp file.

Query String : src=http://demo.webempire.net.au/shi/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/menora2_kitchen011.jpg&w=144&h=94
TimThumb version : 2.8.3
```

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Please note that questions are intended to be *WordPress*-specific, within [the scope as defined in our FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). This question concerns **TimThumb**, which is a third-party PHP script that is not part of WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue.

```
define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', '');
```

was set in timthumb-config.php . This gave me these errors:

```
touch() [<a href='function.touch'>function.touch</a>]: Utime failed: Permission denied in timthumb/timthumb.php on line 469
```

in timthumb/error-log.

Commenting out the line in timthumb-config.php set timthumb.php to use ./cache as the cache folder instead of the system tmp folder, and <strike>fixed</strike> avoided the permission issues.

The problem was that another user already had a timthumb_cacheLastCleanTime.touch in /tmp

Comment: just given 777 Permission to `FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY` Folder & mine problem solved .! Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Wiping didn't work but changing the permissions to 777 did. Via filezilla.

Comment: I hope you realize the problems with setting the security level of any file-system object to 777

Comment: after losing 4 hours on this, changing the cache folder permission to 777 made it work... It's not secure, but defnitly works